# Linear regression and regression line

Tags: regression, machine-learning

The aim of the regression line is to find the line which error is minimum. This error can be calculated by suming all the squares of the difference between the value predicted by the line and the real one. However, some say the average point must belong to line, is this true? Because, if it were that way, that line may not minimize the error.

Comment: What do you mean by average point?

Answer (score 0):

If you think of simple linear regression, you have sum of residuals equal to $0$, i.e. $\sum r_i =0$, where a residual term is $r_i=y_i-ax_i-b$. Substituting this into residual constraint yields:
$$\sum y_i = a\sum x_i+nb\rightarrow \bar y=a\bar x+b$$

So, it passes through $(\bar x, \bar y)$.

Comment: If you have a bias term present, it is equal to 0: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494181/why-the-sum-of-residuals-equals-0-when-we-do-a-sample-regression-by-ols